# Am facing attributeError:2D how do I resolve it

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "afy/cam fomm.py", line 218, in
**predictor_args
File "C:\Users\nzeme\avatarify-python\afy\predictor_local.py", line 49, in init
self.fa face alignment.FaceAlignment (face_alignment. LandmarksType._2D, Flip input=True, device=self.device) File "C:\Users\nzeme\miniconda3/envs\avatarify\lib\enum.py", line 354, in getattr raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: 2D
```

I tried run_windows.bat and I had expected a camera select pop up but I got the result

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "afy/cam fomm.py", line 218, in
**predictor_args
File "C:\Users\nzeme\avatarify-python\afy\predictor_local.py", line 49, in init
self.fa face alignment.FaceAlignment (face_alignment. LandmarksType._2D, Flip input=True, device=self.device) File "C:\Users\nzeme\miniconda3/envs\avatarify\lib\enum.py", line 354, in getattr raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: 2D
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: Run_windows.bat
Am sorry not really a coder am just trying to install an application in my pc

Comment: Again, you need to clarify with more details other than saying "run_windows.bat".

Comment: (avatarify) C:\Users\PREDATOR\avatarify-python>run_windows.bat
[1688971310.212201] Loading Predictor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "afy/cam_fomm.py", line 218, in <module>
    **predictor_args
  File "C:\Users\PREDATOR\avatarify-python\afy\predictor_local.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.fa = face_alignment.FaceAlignment(face_alignment.LandmarksType._2D, flip_input=True, device=self.device)
  File "C:\Users\PREDATOR\miniconda3\envs\avatarify\lib\enum.py", line 354, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: _2D

Comment: What is afy? what does predictor_local.py look like?

Answer (score 4):

change the ._2D to .TWO_D
see (https://github.com/1adrianb/face-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

install this version - pip install face-alignment==1.3.3

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
try:
    self.fa = face_alignment.FaceAlignment(face_alignment. LandmarksType._2D, Flip input=True, device=self.device) 
except:
    self.fa = face_alignment.FaceAlignment(face_alignment. LandmarksType.TWO_D, Flip input=True, device=self.device)
```

Comment: And answer saying to change `_2D` to `TWO_D` was already posted.

Comment: @gre_gor yes, but this snippet supports both old and new face_alignment versions, if you don't want to change the code for other environments. It always happens when you want to offer a more complete solution, someone say part of the code was already answered.